# CoreData: Transformable Type in Entity | Fetch Failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an Entity; `UserDefaults` which has an Attribute; `user_contacts`, i.e is a  list of `Contacts` (NSManagedObject models). I save it comfortably in my .sqlite. However when I try to retrieve it, I get a horrible crash. I use this code to set and fetch my `UserDefaults`;

**SETTING:**

```
for (int k = 0; k < allContactCopy.count; k++)
{
    Contact *contact = [allContactCopy objectAtIndex:k];
    Contact *contactAllData = [Contact getContactForNumber:contact.number];
    contactAllData.reg = NO;
    contactAllData.iD = contact.iD;
    contactAllData.name = contact.name;
    contactAllData.valTag = contact.valTag;
    [contactsAllWithNonRegData addObject:contactAllData];
}

UserDefaults *userD = (UserDefaults*)[[TTDatabaseManager sharedTTDatabaseManager] insertNewMOForModelName:@"UserDefaults"];
userD.user_contacts = [NSArray arrayWithArray:contactsAllWithNonRegData];
[[TTDatabaseManager sharedTTDatabaseManager] saveDataInManagedContext];
```

Consequent calling method is;

```
- (NSManagedObject*)insertNewMOForModelName:(NSString*)modelName
{
    NSManagedObject *objectManaged = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:modelName
                                                                   inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    return objectManaged;
}
```

**FETCHING:**

```
UserDefaults *result = (UserDefaults*)[[TTDatabaseManager sharedTTDatabaseManager] fetchMODataWithModelName:@"UserDefaults" attributeNameToSortBy:@"user_contacts" ascending:NO predicate:nil];
```

And its in consequent calling method is;

```
- (NSManagedObject*)fetchMODataWithModelName:(NSString *)modelName
                   attributeNameToSortBy:(NSString *)attribute
                               ascending:(BOOL)ascending
                               predicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:modelName
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:attribute
                                                                   ascending:ascending];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchResults = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                     error:&error];//IT CRASHES HERE

    if (fetchResults == nil)
    {
        // Handle the error.
        NSLog(@"executeFetchRequest failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else if(fetchResults && [fetchResults count] > 0)
    {
        managedObject = [fetchResults objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return managedObject;
}
```

It crashes where `self.managedObjectContext` executes the request. I have been ramming my head for over a day now and cannot find why its happening so. Your help is appreciated. Crash details are:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Contact initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9d61c708e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bfb8d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b6a6deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   Foundation                          0x0000000109584bda -[NSCoder(Exceptions) __failWithExceptionName:errorCode:format:] + 0
3   Foundation                          0x0000000109584dee -[NSCoder(Exceptions) __failWithExceptionName:errorCode:format:] + 532
4   Foundation                          0x00000001094e0859 _decodeObjectBinary + 3589
5   Foundation                          0x00000001094df94d _decodeObject + 281
6   Foundation                          0x0000000109502111 +[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:] + 89
7   CoreData                            0x000000010bb17b63 _prepareResultsFromResultSet + 3411
8   CoreData                            0x000000010bb14fdd newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT + 3293
9   CoreData                            0x000000010bb01bac -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 524
10  CoreData                            0x000000010bb01549 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 377
11  CoreData                            0x000000010bbe6eaf __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 3311
12  CoreData                            0x000000010bbf04dd gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 189
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c7693eb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c74def5 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 393
15  CoreData                            0x000000010bbe15d5 _perform + 197
16  CoreData                            0x000000010bb011b4 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 500
17  CoreData                            0x000000010baff973 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 579
18  tellotalk                           0x0000000107992b24 -[TTDatabaseManager fetchMODataWithModelName:attributeNameToSortBy:ascending:predicate:] + 532
19  tellotalk                           0x00000001079a9b1b -[ChatListViewController viewWillAppear:] + 459
20  UIKit                               0x0000000109da82bd -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 710
21  UIKit                               0x0000000109da8958 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 149
22  UIKit                               0x0000000109d75de7 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 934
23  UIKit                               0x0000000109c13f62 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 317
24  UIKit                               0x0000000109c27e4c _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 95
25  UIKit                               0x0000000109c34147 _afterCACommitHandler + 90
26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010beddc37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010beddba7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bed37fb __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bed30f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
30  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e5adad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
31  UIKit                               0x0000000109c07f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
32  tellotalk                           0x00000001079904ff main + 111
33  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c79d92d start + 1
34  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Please, add how you set the transformation.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Updated. Please review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is all wrong, in particular the problem line is

```
userD.user_contacts = [NSArray arrayWithArray:contactsAllWithNonRegData];
```

Because you have made the attribute transform able `NSCoding` is used to change that array into data to store in the SQLite. Obviously the I archiving process can't create a proper managed object in a context so you get this crash.

You need to get rid of the array and use a relationship instead of an attribute.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying. I'll look into it and get back to you. Please, can you help explain what this means "You need to get rid of the array and use a relationship instead of an attribute."

Comment: you have a transformable attribute, you should replace that with a relationship. if you do then you won't have an array and you won't do any transforming, core data will provide a set instead

Comment: Super, I understand. Can you however recommend me a sample link or code snippet which does the same? I would love an implementation of that sort. Also that will complete the answer and I'll mark it complete. Thank you Wain.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html